# IN Clause Hangs PHPmyadmin - Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries, first query

```
SELECT DISTINCT( timesheetemployeeid ) AS USER_ID 
FROM   timesheet 
WHERE  timesheetemployeeid != '' 
       AND ( timesheetemployeeconfirm = 1 
              OR ( timesheetemployerconfirm = 1 
                   AND ( timesheetdispute = 0 
                          OR timesheetdispute IS NULL ) ) ) 
       AND timesheetemployerremove IS NULL 
       AND ` timesheetdate ` BETWEEN '2018- 05-27' AND '2018-06-02' 
       AND office_id = 8 
       AND timesheetremove IS NULL 
       AND adminnotconfirmed = 0 
       AND timesheet_id NOT IN (SELECT parenttimesheet_id 
                                FROM   timesheet 
                                WHERE  timesheetemployeeid != '' 
                                       AND timesheetdate BETWEEN 
                                           '2018-05-27' AND '2018-06-02' 
                                       AND ( timesheetemployeeconfirm = 1 
                                              OR ( timesheetemployerconfirm = 1 
                                                   AND ( timesheetdispute = 0 
                                                          OR timesheetdispute IS 
                                                             NULL ) 
                                                 ) ) 
                                       AND timesheetemployerremove IS NULL 
                                       AND timesheetremove IS NULL 
                                       AND office_id = 8 
                                       AND ( parenttimesheet_id IS NOT NULL 
                                              OR parenttimesheet_id != '' )) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT( employee ) AS Employee 
FROM   workordercurrent 
WHERE  employee != '' 
       AND office_id = '8' 
       AND schedulestopdate >= '2018-05-27' 
       AND schedulestopdate <= '2018-06- 02'
```

returns `USER_ID` with 200 recrods in  0.1047 seconds 
[image]

Second Query returns `Prodpay` in 0.2834 seconds

```
    SELECT Sum(pay) AS ProdPay 
FROM   (SELECT currentrate * lineitemquantity AS Pay 
        FROM   (SELECT B.currentworkorder_id, 
                       D.lineitems_lineitemid, 
                       D.lineitemquantity, 
                       C.currentrate, 
                       C.currenteffectivedate 
                FROM   payscaleslocal A 
                       JOIN workordercurrent B 
                         ON A.worktype = B.worktype 
                            AND A.workarea = B.workarea 
                       JOIN payscaleloacljobcodes C 
                         ON A.payscaleslocal_id = C.payscaleslocal_id 
                       JOIN workorderlineitems D 
                         ON C.jobcodeid = D.lineitems_lineitemid 
                            AND 
               B.currentworkorder_id = D.workordercurrent_workorderid 
                WHERE  A.payscale = '16' 
                       AND B.employee = '1287' 
                       AND B.office_id = '8' 
                       AND B.schedulestopdate = '2018-05-27' 
                       AND ( B.orderstatus = 2 
                              OR B.orderstatus = 3 ) 
                       AND C.currenteffectivedate <= '2018-05-27' 
                ORDER  BY C.currenteffectivedate DESC) M 
        GROUP  BY lineitems_lineitemid, 
                  currentworkorder_id) K
```

[image]

I am trying to join these 2 queries using the `IN Clause`

```
So in the second Query - I tried changing the B.Employee IN (<Results of the first query>)
```

The problem is, the Query keeps on loading and does not show any results for 5 mins, I have to close phpmyadmin and restart it again.

I am trying to show `user_id` in the first column and respective `prodpay` of that `user_id` in the second column, by joining these 2 queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temp table based on the first query.  Index timesheetemployeeid And then run the IN on that table.  Drop the table after the queries run.